# mouseleave, clearing interval and stopping script

Tags: jquery

I've got this bit of code:

```
slider.controls.next.bind('mouseenter', function() {
    setInterval(clickNextBind, 300);
});
```

working with bxslider so that if the user hovers over the "next" button, the slideshow scrolls  automatically. But I need it to stop when the user moves away from the "next" button.

I tried this:

```
slider.controls.next.bind('mouseleave', function() {
    clearInterval();
});
```

But it doesn't stop the scrolling. How should I be doing this?

MTIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a specific interval id to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval):

```
var interval = 0;
slider.controls.next.bind('mouseenter', function() {
    interval = setInterval(clickNextBind, 300);
});

slider.controls.next.bind('mouseleave', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: perfect! thanks very much Matt. will accept when SO allows me.